# in c# for type safe tree implementation (typesafe node)

Tags: c#, tree, nodes, type-safety

I am looking for /tring to implement a type safe tree implementation in C#.

How can a type safe tree be implemented, without using interfaces (which force to reimplement the tree functionality all over the place) and without using casts?

I have the idea of using tree as common base class, but then type safety is gone. My current approach is usage generics. But I am missing some conversion back to the base type.

Below is a reduced/nonworking example.
The idea is that the returned Nodes support the tree functions, and at the same time they also support their base types behaviour.
I could use the below class without  and inherit from Node, but then then I loose type safety on one hand, and also get problems with inheritance, as the Nodes have already parent classes.

I also toyed with class extensions, but I haven't got anything that is close to a possible solution.

I think i need one small hint on how to continue. Thank you in Advance.

```
public class Node<T>  // .
{
    public Node<T> parent;
    public List<Node<T>> children;

    protected Node()
    {
        children = new List<Node<T>>();
        parent = null;
    }
    protected Node(Node<T> parent)
        : this()
    {

        this.parent = parent;
        parent.addChildren(this);
    }


    protected void addChildren(Node<T> child)
    {
        children.Add(child);
    }
    public Node<T> getRoot() // returns root node
    public List<Node<T>> flatten()  // return 1d-list of all nodes.

}
```

Comment: Can the type of T vary for each node in the tree? Or will it always be the same throughout the entire tree?

Comment: No (only subclasses). But i would like to use the same tree implementation for a different T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a type-safe tree implementation:

```
public class Tree<T> : List<Tree<T>>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Yes, that's it. Simple.

Of course, you could add a constructor or two, and make the `Value` property read-only to make it a little more OOP friendly. And you could easily add the `Parent` property.

Comment: The best ideas are those who are obvious.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I have the idea of using tree as common base class, but then type safety is gone. My current approach is usage generics. But I am missing some conversion back to the base type.

Then constraint the generic type to your base type:

```
public class Node<T> where T: BaseType { ... }
```

Now you can create any tree of the type `Node<MyDerivedType>` as long as `MyDerivedType` derives from `BaseType`.

On a side not, I'd consider modifying the following in your implementation:

1. `Children` should be a property, do not expose a field unless its readonly. Furthermore, you should not expose it as a `List`; that would let anyone add or remove nodes directly which can violate invariants assumed in your implementation. Return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead:

   ```
   private readonly List<T> children;
   public IEnumerable<T> Children => children.Select(c => c);
   ```

   You could return `children` directly as its implicitly convertible to `IEnumerable<T>`; the problem is that anyone can simply cast it back to `List<T>` and modify it. Projecting it protects you from this conversion.
2. Same happens with `Flatten` (the first *f* should be capitalized btw). Consider returning an `IEnumerable<T>` too.